# Is there a good macvim git diff?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, textmate, macvim

I have been using textmate for many years and I just made the switch to macvim and one thing that I used all the time with textmate was the command `git df` which in my .gitconfig was just an alias for

```
[alias]
    df = !git diff | mate
```

and what that did was give me a screen like this

[image]

Is there a replacement in mvim that I can add somewhere for me to get similar behavior

Answer (score 1):

I describe what I use [here](http://jeetworks.org/node/90).

Basically, add the following lines to your "~/.gitconfig":

```
[diff]
    tool = default-difftool

[difftool "default-difftool"]
    cmd = default-difftool.sh $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

With the following wrapper script:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ -f /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim ]]
then
    # bypass mvim for speed
    VIMPATH='/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -g -dO -f'
elif [[ -f /usr/local/bin/mvim ]]
then
    # fall back to mvim
    VIMPATH='mvim -d -f'
else
    # fall back to original vim
    VIMPATH='vimdiff'
fi

$VIMPATH $@
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I added the lines to .gitconfig and created the default-difftool.sh, placing it in my ~/bin, which is in my path. I then ran "git diff <file>", and nothing happens.

Comment: You need to run `git difftool`; I purposely wanted to preserve `git diff` as the native git diff.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the diff one file at a time by doing:

```
git difftool -t vimdiff
```

`vimdiff` can be replaced with `gvimdiff` for gvim, so I would assume you can also replace it with `mvimdiff` for macvim.

I am not sure of a way to pipe the entirety of `git diff` into vim though.